# Problem with swedish characters (åäö) when downloading xml in android

Tags: android, xml, download, special-characters, xmldocument

In my android app, i download a xml file from a server, construct a xml doc out of it, pars it  and display the info in an layout with the usual setText method. However the Swedish characters åäö wont show correctly.

I have no idea how to fix this, any tips?

Comment: I have "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>" in the file, is that not enough?

Comment: You need to encode correctly in your code.

Comment: Where, in the http request code? Or in the xml Document builder?

Comment: Have you given simple-xml a try, it will probably do all of that for you: http://simple.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was the  in the beginning that was not suppose to be there. I'm not really sure why, the xml file is encoded with UTF-8 anyway, but the DocumentBuilder was not able to build a Document out of it when that line was first.

Thanks for the tips that lead me to it!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `eclipse ide` go to `preferences` under `Window menu`, then under `General` node, select `Workspace`, in the window shown, change the `text file encoding` to `UTF8`..

and you can change the encoding per file from its `properties` window

Comment: the file must be saved using utf8 , you can use any text editor to do that, and read as utf8 too

Comment: It did not make a difference... So where in the chain does the special chars get "corrupt"? Saving the xml file in Eclipse with UTF8 encoding -> uploading to server with filezila -> downloading file wia DefaultHttpClient in android -> bulinding a xml org.w3c.dom.Document based on the string via DocumentBuilder -> parse the file and setting the textView.

Comment: try this: open `Notepad` write some swedish characters  in it, then select `Save As`, in the bottom of the saving window, change the Encoding to Utf-8 , and to read it from the server, use `URLConnection` and read whole `bytes` into `ByteArrayOutputStream boas` in the end of the file, use this `new String(boas.toByteArray()),"utf8");` and print it.